# HTML内でPDFを表示した際のリンクによるページ遷移の方法について

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

現在、左に目次一覧、右にPDFを表示したいなと、iframeを利用して単純に作っています。
単純に書くと次のような状態です。

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="name.pdf#page=1" target="pdf">1</a><br />
    <a href="name.pdf#page=10" target="pdf">10</a><br />
    <a href="name.pdf#page=20" target="pdf">20</a><br />
    <a href="name.pdf#page=30" target="pdf">30</a><br />
    <iframe src="about:blank" name="pdf"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

しかし、最初に選んだもの、たとえば20ページを最初にクリックして表示すると、20ページ目が表示されますが、表示されている状態で、1ページや10ページをクリックしたてもなんら反応がありません。

Javascriptを用いて、srcを一度 about:blankにした後、name.pdf#page=XX を開くとページ自体は思い通りにはなりますが、IEだと毎回AcrobatReaderを読み込みなおすためとても重く現実的ではありません。

何らかの方法はございませんでしょうか。